# Lucene, Alternatives to MoreLikeThis?

Tags: lucene

I am building a recommender system for restaurants. Each restaurant is represented in the form of documents. It has the following features(fields), Cuisine, Facilities, Types.

Now, I read about MoreLikeThis Query. It finds similar documents based on term frequencies. So, it ignores for example, two documents with the following Cuisine

"steakhouse australian gluten-free"

because, lucene index doesnot consider them important terms, because they only occur once.

Is there any other query that ignores term frequencies? and just finds similar documents based on largest number of keywords matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a query with the entire contents of the document, by running it through a `QueryParser`, something like:

```
QueryParser myQueryParser = new QueryParser(myFieldName, new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = myQueryParser.parse(QueryParserBase.escape(myDoc.get(myFieldName)));
```

Potential issues would be overlong queries causing poor performance (that is why `MoreLikeThis` attempts to select the best terms to query instead of searching for all of them), or Too Many Clauses exceptions.